# How do I count the pairs of letters in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write code that counts how many pairs are in each string.

For example: "doggy". There are 2 "g"s next to each other so the code's output would be 1. Here is my attempt so far:

```
def count_pairs( s ):
 #add in code to count
 cnt= (len(s))  

 #how many pairs of letters exist

 #return the number of letter pairs in each string
 # aadogbbcatcc would return 3
 #aadogcatcc would return 2
 return 0

 print ( count_pairs("ddogccatppig") )
 print ( count_pairs("dogcatpig") )
 print ( count_pairs("xxyyzz") )
 print ( count_pairs("a") )
 print ( count_pairs("abc") )
 print ( count_pairs("aabb") )
 print ( count_pairs("dogcatpigaabbcc") )
 print ( count_pairs("aabbccdogcatpig") )
 print ( count_pairs("dogabbcccatpig") )
 print ( count_pairs("aaaa") )
 print ( count_pairs("AAAAAAAAA") )
```

Comment: We will not write code for you. Please first make an attempt. Also, please read [this](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems?newreg=1216e0ad88d74ebbab12ba8299cc7e3c).

Comment: I did I just don't understand what to do.

Comment: You did not make an attempt. An attempt would be having some code related to the task you want and not being able to figure out where to go. You wrote a blank method and showed test cases.

Comment: I did try to write the code. But I don't understand what to do.

Comment: You haven't shown any of that effort in your question. Have you read the rules ([help], [mcve])?

Comment: I deleted my try's so you can easily see the code.

Comment: We would much rather see your attempt than the test cases.

Comment: Okay this is my first post so I didn't know what to do.

Comment: I will do the correct way next time.

Comment: That's fine, just please don't argue with us when we're trying to advise you on how to make a post.

Comment: My advice would be to really read the rules I linked you and then edit this question in to one that follows those rules. Specifically, we need to see a [mcve].

Comment: Okay, It wont happen again.

Comment: What result do you expect from `"aaaa"` - 2 or 3?

Comment: 3 pairs. 2 on the outside 1 in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

Try this function:

```
def count_pairs(s):
    pairs_cnt = 0
    unique_chars = set(s)
    for char in unique_chars:
        pairs_cnt += s.count(char + char)
    return pairs_cnt
```

This will get the unique characters in the string - `set(s)` - and count how many times each occurs in pairs in that string - `s.count(char + char)`.

```
>>> count_pairs("ddogccatppig")
3
>>> count_pairs("dogcatpig")
0
>>> count_pairs("xxyyzz")
3
>>> count_pairs("a")
0
>>> count_pairs("abc")
0
>>> count_pairs("aabb")
2
>>> count_pairs("dogcatpigaabbcc")
3
>>> count_pairs("aabbccdogcatpig")
3
>>> count_pairs("dogabbcccatpig")
2
>>> count_pairs("aaaa")
2
>>> count_pairs("AAAAAAAAA")
4
```

Answer (score 0):

That should do the trick:

```
    cnt=0
    pair=0
    while (cnt < (len(s)) - 1):
        x = s[cnt]
        y = s[cnt+1]
        if x == y:
            pair += 1
        cnt += 1
    return pair
```

Comment: that should do the tirck

Comment: Adding explanation about code will be helpful for OP

Answer (score 0):

using Counter in python3

```
from collections import Counter
def countPairs(word):
    D = Counter(word)
    pairs = 0
    for i in D.keys():
        if D[i] >= 2:
            pairs+=1
    return pairs

print(countPairs(input()))
```